# Can't get value from third column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My `JTable` has 3 columns and I get values from 1st and 2nd column, but from cell in third column i can't :) just doesn't work and i don't know why...
Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (Listener.intervencijeTableZK.getRowCount()) - 1; i++) {
    idIntervencije = idIntervencije + 1;
    Object datumIntervencije = ListenerKalendarZK.datumZaBazu;
    Object zubIntervencije =  Listener.intervencijeTableZK.getValueAt(i, 1);
    Object intervencija = Listener.intervencijeTableZK.getValueAt(i, 2);

    int idPacijenta = value;

    stmtIntervencijaTable.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ordinacijadb.intervencija VALUES('" + idIntervencije + "','" + datumIntervencije + "','" + zubIntervencije + "','" + intervencija + "','" + idPacijenta + "')");

}
```

Object `datumIntervencije` gets value from cell first column, `zubIntervencije` get value from second column, and object `intervencija` never take value from third column... 
Can anyone tell me where i made misstake?
Im working in java, eclipse Helios...

Comment: Are you seeing an error? Is it null? What does 'not working' mean here?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that JTable indices start at 0, whereas you are starting to `getValueAt(i, 1)` at 1?

Comment: There is no error.. it just dont get value from that cell and put in my database null value... That field(cell) in database is empty after executing update...

Comment: @kw4nta, u see line before (i, 1)... that line already took value from (i, 0)... all works fine except (i, 2)

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for TableModel caused with a.m. issue

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kelopatra, i know java naming conventions but there are some reasons that i HAD to use my language when i named some objects and atributes... I'm sorry for that, but i think all here can understand every line in my code...

Comment: didn't mean the localized names but the capitalized ListenerXX ... or are those class methods? Hope not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue... Solution is pretty simple but a bit hard to detect for me :-/ I said that I put values manually in all cells. Thing is that when i press the button to save all in database, focus is still on last cell that i filled and JTable still see that cell as empty. So, before saving all data from JTable, focus should be OFF that last cell so JTable can get that value...

Thanks all for help and effort... :)

Comment: ahhh ... that ominous not-terminating edits bug (some call it feature ;-) That's indeed hard to spot, +1

Answer (score 2):

Try to call

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2);
```

Comment: Didnt worked... I also have model for my table and i tried
Object intervencija = Listener.intervencijeTableModel.getValueAt(i, 2);
...also didnt work :(

Comment: Are you sure that there isn´t null in the third column? And Please post the Exception which is thrown.

Comment: i manually put values in all cells in table, then i save in database those values with that statement that u see in my code... Also, there is no Exception... Eclipse take values from all cells and save these values in database, except from cell (i, 2)...

Comment: Here is another issue... If You didn't notice, my table have 3 columns. All that happens when i have only one row... if i have more rows, it is all fine except last row.. in last row it again don't save value from that cell... For example, if i have 3 rows, all values are saved except last field in last row.. this is too strange for me :-/